# Complex code for many fisher.test p-values in R

Tags: r

I am a beginner in R, so the following is highly complex for me.

I have the following `data.frame` with data from the 5 boroughs of New York city and years 2012-2015. For each year, there are two categories: P and Q.

**Data**

```
 input_df = data.frame(
      Manhattan=c(1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), 
      Brooklyn=c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0), 
      Queens=c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0), 
      The_Bronx=c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0), 
      Staten_Island=c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), 
      "2012"=c("P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "Q", "Q", "Q", "Q", "Q", "Q", "Q", "Q", "Q"), 
      "2013"=c("P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "Q", "Q", "P", "P", "P", "P", "Q", "Q", "Q", "Q", "Q"), 
      "2014"=c("P", "P", "P", "Q", "Q", "P", "P", "Q", "Q", "Q", "Q", "Q", "P", "Q", "P", "P", "P", "Q", "Q"), 
      "2015"=c("P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "Q", "Q", "Q", "P", "Q", "P", "P", "Q", "Q", "Q", "Q", "Q", "Q", "Q"), 
 check.names=FALSE)
```

I would like to systematically determine whether in any two boroughs incidents ("1") occurred at the same time for category P more frequently than for category Q (or vice versa), using `fisher.test`.

So, for example: in 2012, did incidents in Manhattan and Brooklyn occur at the same time (both "1" in the same row) more frequently in category P than in category Q? This is 4 out of 10 for P and 0 out of 9 for Q, so `fisher.test(matrix(c(4,6,0,9), nrow=2))$p.value` equals `0.08668731`.

Is there a way to systematically do this? See below for a simple start and my ideal output `data.frame`. I would be happy with anything even close to this output. Thank you.

**Code (only a start)**

```
 library(reshape2)
 input_df <- melt(input_df, measure.vars = 6:9) # transform the data
 # can maybe use: function x {fisher.test(matrix(x, nrow=2))}
 # how to proceed?
```

**Ideal output**

```
 # ideally hoping to get output similar to this:
 output_df = data.frame(
 borough_1=c("Manhattan", "Manhattan", "Manhattan", "Manhattan", "Manhattan", "Manhattan", "etc"), 
 borough_2=c("Brooklyn", "Brooklyn", "Brooklyn", "Brooklyn", "Queens", "Queens", "etc"),
 year=c("2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2012", "2013", "etc"), 
 P_both_boroughs_1=c("4", "2", "1", "2", "4", "4", "etc"), 
 P_not_both_boroughs_1=c("6", "11", "8", "6", "6", "8", "etc"), 
 Q_both_boroughs_1=c("0", "2", "3", "2", "1", "1", "etc"), 
 Q_not_both_boroughs_1=c("9", "5", "7", "9", "8", "6", "etc"), 
 fisher.test.pval=c("0.086687307", "0.586790506", "0.582043344", "1", "0.303405573", "0.602683179", "etc"), 
 check.names=FALSE)
```

**EDIT for @user2974951**

user2974951, might you please help me run the same code smoothly on the following alternative `input_df`? If I use this `input_df`, it unfortunately throws an error, because `tmp3` is no longer a 2x2 table. I would really appreciate your help. Thank you.

```
 input_df = data.frame(
      Manhattan=c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), 
      Brooklyn=c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0), 
      Queens=c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0), 
      The_Bronx=c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0), 
      Staten_Island=c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), 
      "2012"=c("P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "Q", "Q", "Q", "Q", "Q", "Q", "Q", "Q", "Q"), 
      "2013"=c("P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "Q", "Q", "P", "P", "P", "P", "Q", "Q", "Q", "Q", "Q"), 
      "2014"=c("P", "P", "P", "Q", "Q", "P", "P", "Q", "Q", "Q", "Q", "Q", "P", "Q", "P", "P", "P", "Q", "Q"), 
      "2015"=c("P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "Q", "Q", "Q", "P", "Q", "P", "P", "Q", "Q", "Q", "Q", "Q", "Q", "Q"), 
 check.names=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my attempt using for loops

```
res=vector("list",4)
names(res)=colnames(input_df)[6:9]
for (k in 1:4) { #years
  res[[k]]=matrix(NA,5,5)
  rownames(res[[k]])=colnames(res[[k]])=colnames(input_df)[1:5]
  for (i in 1:4) { #first in par
    for (j in (i+1):5) { #second in pair
      tmp1=which(input_df[,k+5]=="P")
      tmp2=which(input_df[,k+5]=="Q")
      tmp3=table(input_df[tmp1,i],input_df[tmp1,j]) #table for P
      tmp4=table(input_df[tmp2,i],input_df[tmp2,j]) #table for Q
      tmp5=matrix(c(tmp3[2,2],sum(tmp3)-tmp3[2,2],
                    tmp4[2,2],sum(tmp4)-tmp4[2,2]),nrow=2,byrow=T)
      res[[k]][i,j]=fisher.test(tmp5)$p.value
    }
  }
}
```

and the output of all the p-values

```
res

$`2012`
              Manhattan   Brooklyn    Queens The_Bronx Staten_Island
Manhattan            NA 0.08668731 0.3034056 0.3034056             1
Brooklyn             NA         NA 1.0000000 1.0000000             1
Queens               NA         NA        NA 0.3498452             1
The_Bronx            NA         NA        NA        NA             1
Staten_Island        NA         NA        NA        NA            NA

$`2013`
              Manhattan  Brooklyn    Queens  The_Bronx Staten_Island
Manhattan            NA 0.6026832 0.6026832 0.30469556     0.3684211
Brooklyn             NA        NA 1.0000000 0.03611971     0.3684211
Queens               NA        NA        NA 1.00000000     1.0000000
The_Bronx            NA        NA        NA         NA     0.1228070
Staten_Island        NA        NA        NA         NA            NA

$`2014`
              Manhattan  Brooklyn    Queens The_Bronx Staten_Island
Manhattan            NA 0.5820433 0.1408669 0.6284830             1
Brooklyn             NA        NA 0.2105263 1.0000000             1
Queens               NA        NA        NA 0.3498452             1
The_Bronx            NA        NA        NA        NA             1
Staten_Island        NA        NA        NA        NA            NA

$`2015`
              Manhattan Brooklyn    Queens The_Bronx Staten_Island
Manhattan            NA        1 0.6026832 0.6026832     0.4210526
Brooklyn             NA       NA 0.4853801 1.0000000     0.4210526
Queens               NA       NA        NA 0.3188854     1.0000000
The_Bronx            NA       NA        NA        NA     1.0000000
Staten_Island        NA       NA        NA        NA            NA
```

Alternatively if you want it all in one data frame with additional information

```
res=matrix(NA,4*choose(5,2),8)
colnames(res)=c("borough_1","borough_2","year","P_both_boroughs_1",
                "P_not_both_boroughs_1","Q_both_boroughs_1",
                "Q_not_both_boroughs_1","fisher.test.pval")
m=1
for (k in 1:4) { #years
  for (i in 1:4) { #first in par
    for (j in (i+1):5) { #second in pair
      tmp1=which(input_df[,k+5]=="P")
      tmp2=which(input_df[,k+5]=="Q")
      tmp3=table(input_df[tmp1,i],input_df[tmp1,j]) #table for P
      tmp4=table(input_df[tmp2,i],input_df[tmp2,j]) #table for Q
      tmp5=matrix(c(tmp3[2,2],sum(tmp3)-tmp3[2,2],
                    tmp4[2,2],sum(tmp4)-tmp4[2,2]),nrow=2,byrow=T)
      res[m,]=c(colnames(input_df)[i],
                colnames(input_df)[j],
                colnames(input_df)[k+5],
                tmp5[1,1],tmp5[1,2],tmp5[2,1],tmp5[2,2],
                fisher.test(tmp5)$p.value)
      m=m+1
    }
  }
}
```

and first few rows of output

```
data.frame(res)

  borough_1     borough_2 year P_both_boroughs_1 P_not_both_boroughs_1
1 Manhattan      Brooklyn 2012                 4                     6
2 Manhattan        Queens 2012                 4                     6
3 Manhattan     The_Bronx 2012                 4                     6
4 Manhattan Staten_Island 2012                 1                     9
5  Brooklyn        Queens 2012                 1                     9
6  Brooklyn     The_Bronx 2012                 2                     8
  Q_both_boroughs_1 Q_not_both_boroughs_1   fisher.test.pval
1                 0                     9 0.0866873065015479
2                 1                     8  0.303405572755418
3                 1                     8  0.303405572755418
4                 0                     9                  1
5                 1                     8                  1
6                 1                     8                  1
```

**Edit:** as a fix for the missing levels you can use your own table function

```
myTable=function(t1,t2) {
  res=matrix(NA,2,2)
  res[1,1]=sum(t1==0 & t2==0)
  res[1,2]=sum(t1==0 & t2==1)
  res[2,1]=sum(t1==1 & t2==0)
  res[2,2]=sum(t1==1 & t2==1)
  return(res)
}
```

use this instead of `table`.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, it throws an error: Error in `[.default`(tmp3, 2, 2) : subscript out of bounds. I am not sure what this error means.

Comment: @SylviaRodriguez That's strange, it works for me. Did you use some other data with a different structure?

Comment: I apologize. I tried it again and it worked this time. I may have had another package loaded that interfered, because after I cleared the environment and ran it again, it worked, so apologies ... and THANK YOU so much! This is awesome. Exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Thanks again for your code. I love the code you wrote above under "Alternatively if you want to ..." and have been using it. In my real data, there are sometimes many zeroes. For example, if I run your code on the new `df` (please see edit above), then it throws an error, because `tmp3` is no longer a 2x2 table. Might you please help me solve this too? I would very much appreciate it. Thank you so very much. - Syl

Comment: Wow, this is absolutely genius! Exceptional! Thank you so much. - Syl.

Comment: I have one last question, please. I sometimes get the error: `Error in fisher.test(tmp5) : all entries of 'x' must be nonnegative and finite`. Is there a way to prevent such error too, please? If not, then I'll settle for the already excellent code that you gave me. Thank you very much. - Syl.

Comment: @SylviaRodriguez Can you post an example - data when this happens?

Answer (score 2):

I would solve this problem as follows. First of all I load the packages I'll use for the analysis

```r
# packages
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
```

and create the dataset.

```r
# data
input_df <- tibble(
  Manhattan = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0),
  Brooklyn = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0),
  Queens = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0),
  The_Bronx = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0),
  Staten_Island = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0),
  "2012" = c("P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "Q", "Q", "Q", "Q", "Q", "Q", "Q", "Q", "Q"),
  "2013" = c("P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "Q", "Q", "P", "P", "P", "P", "Q", "Q", "Q", "Q", "Q"),
  "2014" = c("P", "P", "P", "Q", "Q", "P", "P", "Q", "Q", "Q", "Q", "Q", "P", "Q", "P", "P", "P", "Q", "Q"),
  "2015" = c("P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "Q", "Q", "Q", "P", "Q", "P", "P", "Q", "Q", "Q", "Q", "Q", "Q", "Q")
)
head(input_df)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 9
#>   Manhattan Brooklyn Queens The_Bronx Staten_Island `2012` `2013` `2014`
#>       <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>         <dbl> <chr>  <chr>  <chr> 
#> 1         1        0      1         1             0 P      P      P     
#> 2         1        0      1         1             0 P      P      P     
#> 3         0        0      0         0             0 P      P      P     
#> 4         1        1      0         0             0 P      P      Q     
#> 5         1        0      1         0             0 P      P      Q     
#> 6         1        1      1         0             0 P      P      P     
#> # ... with 1 more variable: `2015` <chr>
```

Then I change your dataset from a wide structure to a long structure. The columns `year` and `borough` takes the values `2012`, ..., `2015` and `Manhattan`, ..., `Staten_Island` while the columns `category` and `flag` takes the corresponding values for that combination of `borough` and `year` in your dataset. I need this structure for subsequent functions.

```r
# tidying
tidy_input_df <- input_df %>%
  gather("year", "category", `2012`:`2015`) %>%
  gather("borough", "flag", -category, -year)
tidy_input_df
#> # A tibble: 380 x 4
#>    year  category borough    flag
#>    <chr> <chr>    <chr>     <dbl>
#>  1 2012  P        Manhattan     1
#>  2 2012  P        Manhattan     1
#>  3 2012  P        Manhattan     0
#>  4 2012  P        Manhattan     1
#>  5 2012  P        Manhattan     1
#>  6 2012  P        Manhattan     1
#>  7 2012  P        Manhattan     1
#>  8 2012  P        Manhattan     0
#>  9 2012  P        Manhattan     1
#> 10 2012  P        Manhattan     1
#> # ... with 370 more rows
```

I'll need also a vector containing the names of all boroughs

```r
borough <- unique(tidy_input_df$borough)
```

Now I have to modify your dataset in such a way that, for every year, I have two columns which contains every possible couple of two boroughs (i.e. Manhattan - Brooklyn, Manhattan - Queens and so on) with the corresponding values. Since I need to repeat the same procedure for each year I nest the data wrt year

```r
nested_input_df <- nest(tidy_input_df, -year)
nested_input_df
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>   year  data             
#>   <chr> <list>           
#> 1 2012  <tibble [95 x 3]>
#> 2 2013  <tibble [95 x 3]>
#> 3 2014  <tibble [95 x 3]>
#> 4 2015  <tibble [95 x 3]>
```

and create a new function which performes that procedure I described above. I can use now the `nest` - `map` approach described [here](http://ijlyttle.github.io/isugg_purrr/presentation.html).

The first part of the function create a new column in the dataframe which represent a unique ID for each combination of category and borough, while the second part of the code creates a new dataframe with all combinations of boroughs taken 2 at a time and associate the corresponding values of flag and category (i.e. 0/1 and P/Q).

```r
create_boroughs_combinations <- function(data, borough) {
  # Create a unique ID for all combinations of category
  # and borough
  data <- data %>%
    group_by(category, borough) %>%
    mutate(ID = 1:n()) %>%
    ungroup()

  # Create all combinations of n boroughs taken 2 at a time. 
  t(combn(length(borough), 2)) %>%
  # transorm that matrix in a tibble
    as_tibble(.name_repair = ~ c("borough_1", "borough_2")) %>%
  # associate each matrix value to the corresponding borough name
    mutate(borough_1 = borough[borough_1], borough_2 = borough[borough_2]) %>%
  # join the two dataframes wrt the name of the first borough
    inner_join(data, by = c("borough_1" = "borough")) %>%
  # joint the two dataframes wrt the name of the second column, the category
  # and the unique ID
    inner_join(data, by = c("borough_2" = "borough", "category", "ID")) %>%
  # create a new variable that checks if the incidents occurred at the same time
    mutate(equal = factor(flag.x == 1 & flag.y == 1, levels = c(TRUE, FALSE)))
}
```

Now I can apply that function to `nested_input` using the `map` function. I have to use `map` since I need to apply that function separately for each year. This is the result. `flag.x` is the value of `flag` for the first borough while `flag.y` is the value of `flag` for the second borough.

```
unnested_input_df <- nested_input_df %>%
  mutate(data = map(data, create_boroughs_combinations, borough = borough)) %>%
  unnest()
unnested_input_df
#> # A tibble: 760 x 8
#>    year  borough_1 borough_2 category flag.x    ID flag.y equal
#>    <chr> <chr>     <chr>     <chr>     <dbl> <int>  <dbl> <fct>
#>  1 2012  Manhattan Brooklyn  P             1     1      0 FALSE
#>  2 2012  Manhattan Brooklyn  P             1     2      0 FALSE
#>  3 2012  Manhattan Brooklyn  P             0     3      0 FALSE
#>  4 2012  Manhattan Brooklyn  P             1     4      1 TRUE 
#>  5 2012  Manhattan Brooklyn  P             1     5      0 FALSE
#>  6 2012  Manhattan Brooklyn  P             1     6      1 TRUE 
#>  7 2012  Manhattan Brooklyn  P             1     7      0 FALSE
#>  8 2012  Manhattan Brooklyn  P             0     8      0 FALSE
#>  9 2012  Manhattan Brooklyn  P             1     9      1 TRUE 
#> 10 2012  Manhattan Brooklyn  P             1    10      1 TRUE 
#> # ... with 750 more rows
```

Now I can use same idea and create a new function which estimates the pvalue of the fisher test and apply it to every combination of year and couple of boroughs. I nest again my data:

```
nested_input_df <- unnested_input_df %>%
  nest(-year, -borough_1, -borough_2)
nested_input_df
#> # A tibble: 40 x 4
#>    year  borough_1 borough_2     data             
#>    <chr> <chr>     <chr>         <list>           
#>  1 2012  Manhattan Brooklyn      <tibble [19 x 5]>
#>  2 2012  Manhattan Queens        <tibble [19 x 5]>
#>  3 2012  Manhattan The_Bronx     <tibble [19 x 5]>
#>  4 2012  Manhattan Staten_Island <tibble [19 x 5]>
#>  5 2012  Brooklyn  Queens        <tibble [19 x 5]>
#>  6 2012  Brooklyn  The_Bronx     <tibble [19 x 5]>
#>  7 2012  Brooklyn  Staten_Island <tibble [19 x 5]>
#>  8 2012  Queens    The_Bronx     <tibble [19 x 5]>
#>  9 2012  Queens    Staten_Island <tibble [19 x 5]>
#> 10 2012  The_Bronx Staten_Island <tibble [19 x 5]>
#> # ... with 30 more rows
```

define the function:

```r
run_fisher_test <- function(data) {
  data <- data %>%
    select(category, equal)

  fisher.test(table(data))$p.value
}
```

apply it and this is the result:

```r
result <- nested_input_df %>%
  mutate(p.value = map_dbl(data, run_fisher_test)) %>%
  select(-data)
result
#> # A tibble: 40 x 4
#>    year  borough_1 borough_2     p.value
#>    <chr> <chr>     <chr>           <dbl>
#>  1 2012  Manhattan Brooklyn       0.0867
#>  2 2012  Manhattan Queens         0.303 
#>  3 2012  Manhattan The_Bronx      0.303 
#>  4 2012  Manhattan Staten_Island  1     
#>  5 2012  Brooklyn  Queens         1     
#>  6 2012  Brooklyn  The_Bronx      1     
#>  7 2012  Brooklyn  Staten_Island  1     
#>  8 2012  Queens    The_Bronx      0.350 
#>  9 2012  Queens    Staten_Island  1     
#> 10 2012  The_Bronx Staten_Island  1     
#> # ... with 30 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2019-09-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

I hope it's clear. Comment on this post if you have any doubt. I know this is not the easiest approach but I really like the `nest` - `map` approach and it's quite flexible if you understand it.